# How can I change my code to print only x amount of graphs?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Below is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv(r"/Users/aaronhuang/Desktop/ffp/exfileCLEAN2.csv", skiprows=[1]) # replace. 
this with wherever the  file is.

magnitudes = df['Magnitude '].values
times = df['Time '].values
zscores = np.abs(stats.zscore(magnitudes, ddof=1))
outlier_indicies = np.argwhere(zscores > 3).flatten()
print(times[outlier_indicies])


import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, axes = plt.subplots(6, 10, figsize=(30,30))

for i in range(6):
    for j in range(10):
        x = df.iloc[j*10:(j+1)*10,:]
        axes[i][j].plot(x['Time '], x['Magnitude '])
        axes[i][j].set_xticklabels(x['Time '], rotation=45)
plt.show()
```

It prints all the graphs at once (60), how can i change it to print less, for example, 30 graphs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to change these 3 lines.

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(6, 10, figsize=(30,30))

for i in range(6):
    for j in range(10):
```

They are running 6 * 10 so in total `60`. If you want for example 50 you change that into

```py
fig, axes = plt.subplots(5, 10, figsize=(30,30))

for i in range(5):
    for j in range(10):
```

So, you have to change the parameters in the`range()`and`subplots()`.

A better way is to declare two variables to control the size, like this:

```py
width = 5
height = 10
fig, axes = plt.subplots(width, height, figsize=(30,30))
for i in range(width):
    for j in range(height):
```

Now you can simply change the scale by changing the values ​​of the two variables.